# How to split multiple interger value into array of index

Tags: java, list, arraylist, split

I have some `Integer`s inside of an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new AraayList<Integer>();
al.add(100);
al.add(211);
```

Now I want to split the values in the `ArrayList` into an array. Suppose `100` is the first value in the `ArrayList` then the corresponding array should contain `1`, `0`, `0`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: ["3. Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Current state of your question doesn't fulfill these requirements. Use [edit] option to improve it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8+ you can use streams with this trick :

```
List<Integer> result = al.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf) 
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("")))
        .map(Integer::valueOf) 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Details**

- `.map(String::valueOf)` this will convert your Integer to String `eg.` `100 => "100"`
- `.flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("")))` this will create a Stream by the split with `""` eg. `"100" => ["1", "0", "0"]`
- `.map(Integer::valueOf)` this will parse each String to Integer eg. `["1", "0", "0"] => [1, 0, 0]`
- `.collect(Collectors.toList());` this will collect all the result in a list eg. `[1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1]`

Comment: Nice answer, although it shows one real problem with .stream() ...using // inline comments ... everything turns out pretty unreadable ;-)

Comment: I agree @GhostCat I fix it now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can run through the each element in a for loop or foreach since Java 8. Then in the loop you could convert it to a String with

```
yourNumberAsString = String.valueOf(yourNumberInArray);
```

With

```
yourNumberAsString.charAt(0);
```

you get the position of the first digit, with 100 it would be 1. If you do that   dynamically in another for loop your work is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array, convert the *Integer* in *String* and use *Split* method to get *String* array:

```
for(int i=0; i < al.size(); i++)
{
   String [] array = al[i].toString().split("");
   // do whatever you need with the array
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this info. below is the code which i am going to use in my project.

 ArrayList al= new ArrayList();
        al.add(100);
        al.add(200);

        for(int i=0; i < al.size(); i++)
        {
            array = al.get(i).toString().split("");
            System.out.println("Size of array is"+array.length);
            for(int j=0;j<=2;j++) {
                System.out.println("size at position"+j+" is "+array[j]);
            }

        }